# 'Convert' Dictionary<string,int> into List<object>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `Dictionary<string,int> dictionary1` and I need to convert it into a `List<Data>` where `Data` has the properties `lable` = dictionary1.key and `value` = dictionary1.value. I don't want to use a for/foreach loop (written by myself) because in order to avoid it I am trying to use a Dictionary.

Another option would be having two different dictionaries (dictionary2 and dictionary3) where `dictionary2<string,keyOfDictionary1>` and `dictionary3<string,valueOfDictionary1>`.

Do I make sense? Is that possible? Is there a better option?

Comment: "don't want to use a loop" is going to be difficult. You're going to _have_ to iterate the dictionary _somehow_.

Comment: You are getting quite a number of `LINQ` answers - just be aware that  the `LINQ` library still essentially runs a `foreach` in order to return a result.

Comment: All (current) answers contain the key ingredient - a Select transform. This _will_ perform an iteration on the dictionary, however you're doing it without a "loop". Agreeing with Tim Schmelter, I suspect you just don't want the syntactic ugliness of a for/foreach?

Comment: "don't want to use a loop"   :O ? That's IMPOSSIBLE. AFAIK even all the LINQ extension methods use "loops" (optimized) behind the scene.

Comment: What I meant was that I didn't want to explicitly use an unnecessary loop. I know that implicitly there must be one or more in a way that's more efficient then one that I would do. I did not want to write (myself) a new for/foreach loop for that.

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear. Sorry!

Comment: That's what the edit button is for, nothing to be sorry about. =)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming:

```
class Data
{
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dic;
List<Data> list = dic.Select(p => new Data { Label = p.Key, Value = p.Value }).ToList();
```

Comment: It should be noted that if you're using a struct, it would be `yourDictionary.Select(p => new YourStruct(p.Key, p.Value )).ToList();`

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you could use LINQ?

```
dictionary1.Select(p => new Data(p.Key, p.Value)).ToList()
```

This is however using `yield` and thus loops in the background...

Comment: this would require `Data` to have a constructor that takes the values as parameters, which is not specified in the question.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Yes, but it's a trivial matter to make it inline initialization if that is what he needs. I am pointing out a technique rather than a copy-paste-ready solution!

Comment: This is necessary for initializing structs, due to immutability.

Answer (score 4):

```
myDictionary.Select(x => new Data(){ label = x.Key, value = x.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that "no loop" actually means "i want LINQ":

```
List<Data> = dictionary1.Select(
    pair => new Data() {
        label = pair.Key,
        value = pair.Value
    })).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class Data
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }

        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> dictionary1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dictionary1.Add("key1", 1);
        dictionary1.Add("key2", 2);

        List<Data> data = dictionary1.Select(z => new Data { Key = z.Key, Value = z.Value }).ToList();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
dictionary1.Select(p => new Data(p.Key, p.Value)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

.NET already has a data type that does what `Data` would do: `KeyValuePair<T1,T2>`.  Dictionary already implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T1,T2>>`, just cast to it.

```
Dictionary<string, int> blah = new Dictionary<string, int>();
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> foo = blah;
```

Comment: Brilliantly simple. Without understanding the needs of the OP, we can't know if it really doesn't need to be any more complicated than this. :)

Comment: I agree that it won't meet needs if `Key` *absolutely* must be renamed `Label`.  But this is the only way to avoid looping AFAIK.  However, even the cast is pointless.  OP could just use the dictionary anywhere they needed an IEnumerable.

Comment: Unfortunately I needed to rename my data to Label. I tried doing this but I would have the same thing as you said. So, thanks a lot for the help and I'm sorry I generated missunderstandings by not explicitly say that I didn't want to write a for/foreach loop myself because I knew that built-in functions would do it for me in a better way (even if a loop in the background was necessary).

Answer (score 1):

This is a old post, but post only to help other persons ;)

Example to convert any object type:

```
public List<T> Select<T>(string filterParam)
{    
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable()

    //{... implement filter to fill dataTable }

    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }

    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(rows);

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T[]));
        var tick = (T[])deserializer.ReadObject(stream);
        return tick.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case just helps anyone, I did it like this - will handle objects more complex than a single value type, as stated by the OP.

```
// Assumes: Dictionary<string, MyObject> MyDictionary;
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();
list.AddRange(MyDictionary.Values.ToArray());
```